# JSON output with Express Mysql

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, express

I have a mysql database successfully connected. I can't seem to get the query data to output anything in the console whether there is an error or not. Is there anything wrong with the way I've set everything up?

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');


var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: "root",
    database: 'photo_gallery'
});

connection.connect();


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.locals.appdata = require('./data.json');

app.use('/', routes);

app.get('/',function(request,response){
connection.query('SELECT title FROM stories', function(err, rows, fields)

   {
            console.log('Connection result error '+err);
            console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
    });

} );   

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to parse the data from mysql into a json object and use that object in my express route in an index.js file set up in a folder titled route in the main directory.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var appdata = require('../data.json');
var mysql = require('mysql');


var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: "root",
    port : 3306, //port mysql
    database: 'photo_gallery'
});

connection.connect();


router.get('/', function(request,response) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM stories', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Encountered an error:', err.message);
      return response.send(500, err.message);
    }
    thedata = ({'services' : rows});
    console.log(thedata);

    response.render('index', { 
    title: 'home',
    data: thedata, 
    page: 'home'
  });
  });
});
```

This snippet from my index.ejs file makes use of the JSON object.

```
<a href="/services/"><li>Service Overview</li></a>
   <% thedata.services.forEach(function(item) { %>
      <a href="/services/<%= item.title %>"><li><%= item.title %></li></a>
  <% }); %>
```

Comment: what is in `var appdata = require('../data.json');` ? Can you please post a git to a whole project or have this module working without dependencies?